# What is best way to display error message that all radio buttons must be selected in an ASP.NET Core MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, client-side, validationsummary

I have a set of radio buttons in my ASP.NET Core MVC view. If "Submit" (save) is clicked without selecting ALL radio buttons, I want to display a message:

> All radio buttons must be selected

in the `@HTML.ValidationSummary` at the top of my view.

What's the best way to achieve this please?

Comment: It would help if you showed what your code currently looks like, so people can point out what needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simplest method is using `ViewBag` instead of `@HTML.ValidationSummary`. `@HTML.ValidationSummary` will show all list of the error messages instead of custom error message by default, So you can try this simple demo:

```
<form method="post">        
    @ViewBag.Error
    <input type="radio"..../>
    ..........


</form>
```

controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(TestModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //set error message
                ViewBag.Error = "All radio buttons must be selected.";
                return View(model);
            }
              .......
           
        }
```

Then, when you don't select all radio buttons and submit the form, The error message will show, You can also add `Css` style to make it look the way you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi,@Plan Man, If this answer can help you solve this issue, Can you mark it as the answer? Thank you so much!